# Is it ok to "delete" memory allocated with "new[1]" and vice-versa?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, new-operator, delete-operator

Is this code legal?

```
int * a = new int[1];
delete a;
```

Or this one?

```
int * a = new int;
delete [] a;
```

Obviously, this doesn't seem right and should be discouraged at the very least but will it cause any actual problems (memory leaks and whatnot)?

Comment: Read [The Old New Thing - Mismatching scalar and vector new and delete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx).

Comment: Why would anyone bother using `delete[]` if `delete` worked with any expression? The answer is no, it isn't ok because it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I know I could write a memory manager where this would be an issue.  Which specific memory manager/compiler are you wondering if this would/could be an issue?

Comment: If you mix them it's not a valid C++ program, so the question isn't very meaningful.

Comment: @franji1: If you care about portability, then you should wonder about all possible conforming implementations, not any specific one.

Comment: Why downvotes? He've asked a legit question. You got an upvote.

Comment: @liran63 "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @MatthiasB **Neither does the question which my question is supposed to be a duplicate of!!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matching combination *must* be:-

`new; delete;`

`new[]; delete[];`

If you mix these up you would get undefined behaviour. I have seen code blowing up due to this.

Comment: if I can add some useless trivia to the "code blowing up" - this bug was present in the shipped version of Red Alert 2 (in an unused feature that was left over from the previous game of the series). It did crash the game if that feature was activated, and it was fun to track it down via IDA and WinDBG.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you `new` you should `delete`. And if you `new[]` you should `delete[]`.

Comment: I know I **should**, I wrote that explicitly myself. My question asks if this will cause any problems (and what exactly they would be).

Comment: It results in undefined behavior if you intermix these.

Comment: Most likely your heap will be corrupted and you will see crashes happen at random points.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing scalar and array (de)allocation operators leads to undefined behaviour. A defined difference between delete and delete[] is that the latter calls the destructors for all elements of the array.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/